# List of messages as content in message

Tags: activemq-cpp

Is there a way to add a list (vector) of messages as content to a message?
I know there is no direct way of doing this, but what would be the workaround to achieve such behavior?

Regards
Klaus

Comment: Can you clarify the question please, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Just as cms::Message has addString(...) etc. I would like to somehow be able to add messages to a message.

Comment: Still not entirely clear what you want to achieve but from the info given I'd say there is no way to do what you are wanting to do.